# Firebase not hosting all webpages in Angular 4 project

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm working on a project [Link to GitHub](https://github.com/S00148095/TheCookbook) whereby I have deploying the website with Firebase as I am already using the Authentication and Database features of Firebase [link to live site](https://the-cookbook.firebaseapp.com/home).

I've gone through the [Quick Start guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart) with the project, however, only a couple of the webpages are actually being displayed on the website.

Inside my `app` folder, I have several components including: `dashboard, generation, header, home, listing, login, meal, recipe, recipe-details, schedule` and `shopping-list`. But only the `home, recipe` and `recipe-details` are the only ones that functions

An example of one component that won't load is the `login` component. There is a route setup to the button in the image, however, it currently does not do anything on click.
[Image of home screen with login button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nunrg.png)

I've run `ng build --prod` and `firebase deploy`, but the website still isn't functionally properly.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does it work locally when you do `ng serve` ? Did you try hosting locally using `firebase serve --only hosting`

Comment: @Muthukumar `ng serve` works fine, but using `firebase serve --only hosting` gives a 404 error saying `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: show your firebase.json file and what is the firebase-admin version you are using in the package.json file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Posting my fix for anyone else who encounters this problem**

In `app.module.ts`, I have a const array called routes which contains all of the routes for the application.

All I did for the fix was change the line `{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent , canActivate: [StorageService]}` to `{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }` and everything has worked fine since then.

Hope this helps someone